# Jquery: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my javascript. It was working well prior to conducting a Git Pull from my partner. On a click the hint loads with fancy box.  The load does not work now.

```
Game = {

loadLevel: function(levelNum) {
    $("#level").load("/level/" + levelNum + "/", function() {

        // disable all hints except the first
        $("#level .hint:not(:first)").prop('disabled', true);

        // clicking a hint displays the hint
        $("#level .hint").each(function(index, el) {
            $(el).fancybox({
                href : $(el).attr("data-url"),
                type : 'ajax',
            });
        });

        // enable next hint when clicking on a hint
        $("#level .hint").on("click", function() {
            $(this).next().prop('disabled', false);
        });

        // if answer is correct load next level
        $("#answer").on("click", function() {
            $.get("/answer/" + levelNum + "/", {
                guess : $('.guess').val()
            }, function(answer) {
                console.log(answer);
                if (answer) {
                    Game.loadLevel(levelNum+1);
                }
            });
        });
    });
},

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 loadLevel: function(levelNum) {
   if (levelNum > 5) return;
   $("#level").load("/level/" + levelNum + "/", function() {
```

I think the problem might be here -- but it could be in code you don't show:

```
               Game.loadLevel(levelNum+1);
```

This will recurse but there is no way to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, it sounds like your partner's code either has an infinatly looping recursive call somewhere or is calling too many functions deep.